# Extracting hex numbers from char array

Tags: c++, c, hex, bit

I need to extract hex numbers from `char*` which length = 16,
for ex. `fa45cb15` and I need to get the value of each bit

How to do it in correct way? Now I'm just printing `printf("%x");`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And do you mean *bit* or *byte*? Should you print e.g. `"fa"` followed by `"45"` etc.?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please show an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not very hard, all you need is a loop and a cast to make sure your numbers are unsigned

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    printf("%02X", (unsigned char)data[i]);
```

Comment: I'm wondering about the down votes. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Because you're not extracting each bit?

Comment: @john Who knows? It is unclear what the OP is asking, and you should vote to close, not give an answer to an unclear question.

Comment: I think you're being a little harsh on a newbie who can't express themselves clearly. If the above answer is wrong for the OP then no harm done. FWIW I think it pretty clear that the OP has a 16 byte array which they want to print in hex, possibly they want to print or access bits as an additional task, more likely they just want to print in hex so they can see the bit values for themselves.